# How to keep the daemon threads alive after main thread exits?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm working on a python application, in which the main thread creates an object, say `x`, of a particular class.

Then it starts one thread which starts the execution in one of the methods of this object `x`. The method has a `while True:` loop, so its infinite.

Then it starts another thread which starts the execution in another method of the same object `x`. This method also has a `while True:` infinite loop.

I have made both the threads as daemon by calling `t1.setDaemon(True)`, but it seems both stop execution once the main thread exits.

How do I keep the children alive after the parent thread is finished?
Or should I change my design to use a cron job or process fork?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says

> A thread can be flagged as a "daemon thread". The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The flag can be set through the daemon property.

If you want to keep your program running, you must have at least one non daemon thread.